# Input text type error with autocomplete

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome

I have an input element that doesn't accept a text from autocomplete from recommendation dropdown (values that I have sometime already entered). Code is as simple as it gets:

```
<input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" required>
```

Input holder paints yellow and when I process a form, script isn't executed correctly. I don't seem to get an error in console either. Using google chrome. Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: Check your browser settings. if autocomplete may be disable

Answer (score 0):

its work. 
when the name is stored presses submit

```
<form>
  <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" required autocomplite="on">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```